# SSRS/SQL How to plot HH:mm:ss on graph?

Tags: sql, time, graph, reporting-services

Hi all this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to plot a chart that displays names of some schedules we run, and their total run time duration. What I'm trying to achieve is to show our 5 slowest schedules. SQL data output is something like this:

[SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaxnA.png)

Note for elapsed above, this is currently cast as TIME, however I have also had it in the format of 03:19:02 without the milliseconds afterwards as well by using CONVERT VARCHAR 108.

[My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2rtP.png)

In the screenshot above you can see the schedule numbers on the left and the elapsed time on the bottom.

Things I have tried so far:

Setting the format under number to HH:mm or HH:mm:ss. Neither of these work, when I do this it results in this:

[My attempt at custom Number formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfTMG.png)

[How it looks after I save the number format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAWCe.png)

As you can see it just plots a ridiculous HH:mm continuously on the bottom axis as opposed to an actual time. This happens whether my data is plotted as convert varchar 108 or CAST as TIME.

I've also attempted to go under Axis Options and changed Interval type to Hours or days or minutes etc, if I try any of those the axis just disappears as below:

[Interval Type Changed to Hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npqxo.png)

[Interval Type Changed to Hours output with disappearing axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRqED.png)

Let me know what I'm doing wrong in the above team! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not showing the actual duration but a count (which is always 1).

Look under Chart Data / Values and make sure your aggregate is e.g. a MAX and not a COUNT.